# Javascript for a popup. Asp.net for Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

What JavaScript has to be written for a popup when a link is clicked? Correct me if there is anything else to be done.

Link is written like this.

```
<div style="float:left; padding-left:9px;">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkActiveInactive" runat="server" OnClick="lnkActiveInactive_Click"
      CssClass="linkclass" Font-Underline="True">Cancel My Account</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

And popup extender is like this.

```
<cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender DisplayModalPopupID="ModalPopupExtender2" ID="ConfirmButtonExtender2"
    runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkActiveInactive">
</cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" OkControlID="btnYesCancel" CancelControlID="btnNoCancel"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="pnlCancelPopup" TargetControlID="lnkActiveInactive"
    runat="server">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel CssClass="modalPopup" ID="pnlCancelPopup" runat="server">
    <!-- Common Popup Control Begin -->
    <table class="tblCommonPopup" width="690px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="topLeft">
            </td>
            <td class="topMiddle">
            </td>
            <td class="topRight">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="middle" align="center">
                <!-- Content Area Begin -->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">                                             
                                         Feel free to change your package to Basic, there is no charge for this Package.<br /><br />If you still wish to cancel, 
                                         your account will become inactive within DealTown and any further billing will <br />discontinue.  
                                         We will keep you account in our system for some time if you wish to active it again.<br /><br />Are you sure you 
                                         wish to cancel your account?                                                                                           
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="4">
                            <input id="btnYesCancel" type="button" value="YES" class="popupButton" />
                            <input id="btnNoCancel" type="button" value="NO" class="popupButton" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- Content Area Ends -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="bottomLeft">
            </td>
            <td class="bottomMiddle">
            </td>
            <td class="bottomRight">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Common Popup Control End -->
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Did you really have to post _all_ of that? Were the `<table/>` tags really necessary to understanding your question and solving the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript for a popup. Asp.net for Visual Studio 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471582/javascript-for-a-popup-asp-net-for-visual-studio-2005)

Comment: And, **please** don't post duplicate questions!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understood your question clearly, but this is how to pop up in JS

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function Confirmation() {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to Cancel your Account?")
        if (answer){
            alert("Goodbye!")
        }
        else{
            alert("Thanks for not Cancelling")
        }
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    <div style="float:left; padding-left:9px;">
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkActiveInactive" onclick="Confirmation();">Cancel My Account</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

This code is used is you run on the client side.  If you want it to run on server side you have to do it on  the codebehind like such

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    this.lnkActiveInactive.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:Confirmation()");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a confirmation dialog for the 'cancel my account' you can simply place some javascript in your aspx page.

Something like:

onclick="javascript:confirm()"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the other responders have missed that you are using the ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit ModalPopupExtender.

The answer to your question is, no, no Javascript is required. Setting the TargetControlID of the ModalPopupExtender to your LinkButton should be sufficient to get the pop-up to appear. If that's not happening, something else is wrong.

One thing I notice is that you have an OnClick handler on the LinkButton. This shouldn't be necessary if the only function of the link button is to pop up the dialog.